# Otsu algorithm, Canny edge and HOG for multiple images in a folder

Tags: image-processing, classification, image-segmentation, feature-extraction, opencv, python

I have 500 images for each class of 26 classes to perform Otsu, Canny edge and HOG as feature extraction techniques. Euclidian distance, Cosine distance and SVM for classification on it using python. I can apply Canny and HOG on a single a image. How can I do it for all the images with a loop that loop through the folders and save the result images in difference folder class? The features extracted are to use for classification with Euclidian distance, Cosine distance and SVM.

I know glob can be used, but I do not know how to use it for my request

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#Otsu Algorithm
img=cv2.imread('/User/Desktop/Image/A1.jpg')
img=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)\n",
ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(img, 120,300, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Canny edge
edges = cv2.Canny(thresh1, 250, 300)

#creating hog features
from skimage.feature import hog
fd, hog_image = hog(resized_img, orientations=9, pixels_per_cell=(8, 8), tcells_per_block=(2, 2), 
             visualize=True, multichannel=False)
```

I tried below line codes, yet to solve my challenges. The code get all the classes in to a folder after grayscale, and also canny edge. I was unable to get the Hog features in a folder. How do I classified this features using SVM,RF and cosine metrics.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob
import os

training_path='Train_Test_directory/dataset/train'
training_names = os.listdir(training_path)

# Get path to all images and save them in a list
image_paths = []
image_classes = []
class_id = 0

def imglist(path):    
    return [os.path.join(path, f) for f in os.listdir(path)]

#Fill the placeholder empty lists with image path, classes, and add class ID number
for training_name in training_names:
    dir = os.path.join(training_path, training_name)
    class_path = imglist(dir)
    image_paths+=class_path
    image_classes+=[class_id]*len(class_path)
    class_id+=1

grey_list = []
incre=0
for image_path in image_paths:
    image = cv2.imread(image_path, 0)  
    grey_list.append(image)
    cv2.imwrite('Train_Test_directory/grey/001'+str(incre)+'.jpg',image)
    incre +=1
canny_list = []   

# Read in each image and convert to grayscale
incre=0
for image_path1 in grey_list:
    canny = cv2.Canny(image_path1, 200, 255)
    canny_list.append(canny)
    cv2.imwrite('Train_Test_directory/canny/001'+str(incre)+'.jpg',canny)
    incre +=1

HOG_list=[]
incre=0
#creating hog features
from skimage.transform import resize
from skimage.feature import hog

for image_path3 in canny_list:

    fd, hog_image = hog(resize(image_path3, (128,64)), orientations=9, 
                    pixels_per_cell=(8, 8),cells_per_block=(2, 2), 
                    visualize=True, multichannel=False)
    HOG_list.append(hog_image)
    cv2.imwrite('Train_Test_directory/hog/001'+str(incre)+'.jpg',hog_image)
    cv2.imwrite('Train_Test_directory/hog/001'+str(incre)+'.jpg',fd)
    incre +=1

canny_list= np.array(canny_list)
HOG_list= np.array(HOG_list)
```

Comment: I tried below line codes, yet to solve my challenges. The code get all the classes in to a folder after grayscale, and also canny edge. I was unable to get the Hog features in a folder. How do I classified this features using SVM,RF and cosine metrics.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
from imutils import paths
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array

dir_imagenes = "dataset/lemons/"
print(os.listdir(dir_imagenes)) #green/ mature/
# resize 32x32
SIZE = 32
data = []
labels = [] 

imagePaths = np.array(list(paths.list_images(dir_imagenes)))
#it only load .jpeg, jpg y png.
for (i, imagePath) in enumerate(imagePaths):
    # Extraer la etiqueta en base a la ruta del archivo
    # formato asumido:
    # /path/to/dataset/{class}/{image}.jpg
    label = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-2]
    
    # Cargar imagen desde el disco
    img = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    
    # pasar de BGR a RGB
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    
    # Redimensionar las imágenes para un procesamiento más rápido:
    img = cv2.resize(img, (SIZE, SIZE), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
    
    #Convertir a array la imagen con el pre-procesador de keras
    img = img_to_array(img)
    
    # Agregar imagenes a la lista
    data.append(img)
    labels.append(label)
    
data = np.array(data)
labels =  np.array(labels)
```

Adapt this code to your code, good luck.
PD: Is highly recommend use keras preprocessor